# ¿Cómo insertar correctamente el "No found" en React?

Tags: reactjs, select, input

he estado probando cómo hacer un select personalizado en React debido a que la etiqueta Select por si sola no se puede dar estilos. Lo he conseguido por varios tutoriales pero no encuentro forma de mostar un mensaje el cúal si al momento de escribir un país y no está dentro del array aparezca un mensaje de "Country no found" pero no he podido.

A lo mucho he intentado añadir estilos al country?.name pero simplemente añade el nombre nofound al lado del país que aparece.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./select.css"

export default function Selector(){
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState(null); 
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(""); 
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(""); 
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false); 
  const [nofound, setNoFound] = useState("Country no found")

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://restcountries.com/v2/all?fields=name")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setCountries(data);
        console.log(data)
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="select-0">
      <div 
      onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
      className={`select-1 ${!selected && "slt"}`}>
        {selected 
        ? selected?.length > 25
        ?selected.substring(0, 25) + "..."
        : selected
        : "Select Country"}
        <svg className={`${open && "select-7"}`} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M16.939 7.939 12 12.879l-4.939-4.94-2.122 2.122L12 17.121l7.061-7.06z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <ul className={`select-2 ${
      open ? "slt3" : "slt4"
      }`}
      >
        <div className="select-3">
        <svg className="select-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19.023 16.977a35.13 35.13 0 0 1-1.367-1.384c-.372-.378-.596-.653-.596-.653l-2.8-1.337A6.962 6.962 0 0 0 16 9c0-3.859-3.14-7-7-7S2 5.141 2 9s3.14 7 7 7c1.763 0 3.37-.66 4.603-1.739l1.337 2.8s.275.224.653.596c.387.363.896.854 1.384 1.367l1.358 1.392.604.646 2.121-2.121-.646-.604c-.379-.372-.885-.866-1.391-1.36zM9 14c-2.757 0-5-2.243-5-5s2.243-5 5-5 5 2.243 5 5-2.243 5-5 5z"/></svg>
          <input 
          type="text"
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value.toLowerCase())} 
          placeholder="Enter country name"
          className="select-5"/>
        </div>
        {countries.length === 0 ? (
          <h3>{nofound}</h3>
        ) :
        countries.length > 0 && countries?.map((country) => {
        return (
          <li
          key={country?.name}
          className={`select-6 
          ${
            country?.name?.toLowerCase() === selected?.toLowerCase() && "slt2"}
          ${
            country?.name?.toLowerCase().startsWith(inputValue)
            ? "block"
            : "hidden"
          }
          `}
          onClick={() => {
            if(country?.name?.toLowerCase() !== selected.toLowerCase()){
              setSelected(country?.name);
              setOpen(false);
              setInputValue("")
            }
          }}
          >
            {country.name}
          </li>
        );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Aquí los estilos

```
body{
    background-color: blue;
}

.select-0{
    display: flex;
    width: 18rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    height: 20rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10rem;
}

.select-1{
    display: flex;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.slt{
    color: rgb(97, 97, 97);;
}

.select-2{
    background: white;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 15rem;
}

.select-3{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: white;
}

.select-4{
    fill: rgb(97, 97, 97);
}

.select-5{
    padding: 0.6rem;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-family: inherit;
}

.select-5::placeholder{
    color: rgb(97, 97, 97);
    outline: none;
}

input[type="text"]{
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

.select-6{
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0.6rem;
}

.select-6:hover{
    background-color: skyblue;
    color: white;
}

.slt2{
    background-color: skyblue;
    color: white;
}

.slt3{
    max-height: 15rem;
}

.slt4{
    max-height: 0;
}

.block{
    display: block;
}

.hidden{
    display: none;
}

.select-7{
    transform: rotate(-180deg)
}

.wrapper.active .select-btn i{
    transform: rotate(-180deg)
}
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda a mi problema, sugerencia y optimización de mi código. Gracias de antemano

Comment: as intentando cambiando `const [countries, setCountries] = useState(null); ` a `const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);` solo por curiosidad?

Comment: No, sólo lo dejo tal cual el state, pero cuando tecleo el país en el input la letra A sólo aparecen los países que empiezan con esa letra

Comment: As intentado usar `includes()` ?